# Postfix not sending emails to external domains from mailing client

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, dovecot, fedora

I have just finished setting up postfix and dovecot on my virtual server. I am able to send emails to external email addresses from my Linux console using mailx but when I try to set up mail account on outlook or any other email client then the server returns the below error:

```
454 4.7.1 <info@some-external-domain.com>: Relay access denied
```

Below is my postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = mail.example.com #hiding the actual server name
myhostname = example.com #hiding the actual server name
mynetworks = 192.168.30.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/README_FILES
relayhost =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib64/postfix
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/tls/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/postfix.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First, comment "relayhost =" line at main.cf
Then if it continues failing, provide more logs.
Regards